# Deploy Visual Studio 2010 Database Project

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio-2010

I have a Visual Studio 2010 Database project, from which I want to generate a script
that simply puts up this database to another machine. The problem is that i can't find a
solution for this.

As I started the project, I imported the shema from a database on my development pc.
The Schema Objects were generated and all tables and scripts where under 'Schema Objects -> Schemas -> dbo'. Over the time, some things changed, some where added. And by using right-click -> deploy,
the changes were made to my local database successfully.

But now I want to deploy to another machine. The problem is, that in the release folder of the project, there is only a xml dbschema file containing all tables and scripts that i can't import
with sql management studio (or i just can't find out how) and the a deployment script which is nothing more than some checks followed by the pre- and post- deployment script, but without any tables or scripts in it.

So please, how do i export the database from Visual Studio, so i can easily put it up on another machine?

Comment: In the sql server project properties you can enable a box for generate script .sql which will put a script in the output directory containing all the create/alter commands plus any of your post deploy scripts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it's possible to point your Visual Studio to your new target database? 1. Properties of your Database project, Deploy tab, set the fields in Target Database Settings.

Now when you generate a deploy script, the resulting SQL file will be the various CREATe / ALTER / DROP etc that will align the target database with your schema.

Comment: Ok, that generates a deployment script which has all objects in it. One problem that remains is that there are parts in the code that are not sql (e.g. ':setvar' or ':on error exit') and prevent me from adding it on the other machine. I could remove them manually, but sorry, is this really the easiest way? Nothing like 'Export SQL Create Script'? I am disappointed by Microsoft if so.

Comment: If you run the script from the command line everything will be fine. SQLCMD /i yourdeploymentscript.sql {and other switches as required)}   YOu could also choose to have VS execute the script for you.

Comment: If you are running your script from SQL Server Management Studio, to enable the script to run successfully, open the menu Tools > Options.  Click the “Query Execution” in the list.  Check the “By default, open new queries in SQLCMD mode”.  Open a new query window and run your script. This is necessary to resolve the lines that start with “:”, such as “:setvar”.

Answer (score 14):

Marks--

You likely have already resolved this, but I thought I should answer your questions for the benefit of others.

Yes, you can deploy from Visual Studio to different machines.  You can also do it from the command line, using [VSDBCMD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193283.aspx).  And you can create a [WIX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) project to give a wizard for others to install it with.

If you can connect to the target database from your dev PC, you can deploy to it.  To do this:

1. Select another Configuration from the Solution Configuration drop down.  Normally, the Project will come with "Debug" and "Release" baked in.  You can add another configuration to allow you to deploy to various targets by clicking "Configuration Manager."

[image: Solution Configuration drop down]

2. Right-click your Project and select 'Properties', or simply double-click Properties under the project.
3. Click the Deploy tab.  Notice that the Configuration: drop-down shows the same selected configuration as "active."
4. Change the Deploy Action to "Create a deployment script (.sql) and deploy to the database."
5. Next to Target Connection String, click "Edit" and use the dialog to create your deployment connection to the target database.
6. Fill in the Target database name, if different.
7. For each Deployment Configuration (e.g., Debug, Release, etc.), you will probably want a separate Deployment configuration file.  If you click "New," you can create one for the current configuration.  The new file will open, and you can check and uncheck important things about the deployment.

[image: The .sqldeployment file]

8. Note: If you check **Always re-create the database**, the script will DROP and CREATE your database.  You will lose all your data on the target!  Be careful what you select here.  Most people leave that unchecked for a Production target.  I check it for Development or Local because I want a fresh copy there.
9. Save your changes to the file and to Properties.
10. To deploy to the target, be sure to select the correct Configuration.  Click Build/Deploy [My Database Name].  You probably should experiment with this so you are familiar with how it works before trying it on a live environment.
11. Good practices: build a similar environment to production ("Staging") and deploy there first, to test the deployment, and always back up the database before deploying, in case something goes wrong.

For more info, please see:

- [Working with Database Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee70aty.aspx)
- [Walkthrough: Put an Existing Database Schema Under Version Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833194.aspx)
- [Visual Studio 2010 SQL Server Database Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff678491.aspx)

Comment: post a comment with the links and I can add them for you. And enjoy a +1 while you're at it.

Answer (score 1):

You could always create an empty database and then do a schema compare in Visual Studio between your database project and the new empty database. You can amend the generated schema update script to also create the database (since the script will be to update an existing empty database)

Comment: Isn't that a very uncomfortable way? Is there no other poibility to extract a script for creation?

Comment: It might not be the best way, I don't know, when I've had to do this I've been in too much of a hurry to actually research it.  It does work though and is pretty quick and painless, although I don't doubt that there is probably a better way.