# How to publish database within WPF application? It's connected using LINQ to SQL-Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, linq, visual-studio

I have a WPF application that is connected to a SQL-Server Express Database using LINQ. I haven't worked much with databases before and I'm trying to figure this out as I go, so feel free to correct me if I'm using the wrong terminology.

My goal is to publish the program and have it copy the database so whoever's installing it can look at the information and edit it on their computer or whatever.

I think this is possible for visual studios to do with click once judging by this table: http://erikej.blogspot.co.uk/2011/01/comparison-of-sql-server-compact-4-and.html

If I deploy the program I can of course install it on my own computer, however if I try to install it on another computer I get the error:

`Application download did not succeed. Check your network connections...`

With the details:

```
 Activation of C:\myapp.application resulted in exception.
      + Downloading http://mycomputername/myapp.application did not succeed
```

But I'm not sure why it's trying to download anything from the internet because I published it as installing from a CD-ROM/DVD-ROM.

So I did some research and changed the database .dbml `Build Action` to `Content` and the `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy if Newer` and played around with those settings a bit but that didn't solve my problem.

[image]

I also saw that in MyProject -> Properties -> Settings that my connection string was defined like so:

[image]

How should I change this so that I can deploy the database with the program? I think I it should start with `.\SQLEXPRESS` but that didn't solve my problem either.

I've found other forums about it, but they usually connect to the database manually in the code, whereas LINQ generates code like the following for me so it doesn't seem to apply.

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.DatabaseAttribute(Name="MyDataBase")]
public partial class CustomersDataContext : System.Data.Linq.DataContext
{

    private static System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MappingSource mappingSource = new AttributeMappingSource();

    public CustomersDataContext() : 
            base(global::myApp.Properties.Settings.Default.myConnectionString, mappingSource)
    {
        OnCreated();
    }

    /* more stuff like that */

}

[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.MyTable")]
public partial class MyClass
{  
    /* column definitions */
```

My app is targeted for .NET framework of 4.5, I'm using Visual Studios Professional 2013.

How can I tell Visual Studios to bundle the database with the application and deploy it upon installation?

Thanks a lot for any help.

**Edit:**

Right now to connect my program to the database, I just drag the database in from SQL Server Object Explorer.

[image]

And then can load it as easily as this:

```
        CustomersDataContext cd = new CustomersDataContext();
        var customers = (from p in cd.MyDataBase
                         select p).ToList();
        MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = customers;
```

And edit it as easily as this:

```
            CustomersDataContext dataContext = new CustomersDataContext();
            MyClass newRow = MyDataGrid.SelectedItem as MyClass;

            MyClass row = (from p in dataContext.MyDataBase
                                 where p.ID == customerRow.ID
                                 select p).Single();
            row = newRow;
            dataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

I'd really prefer something that doesn't change the way I interact with the DB because that's going to make me rebuild the whole thing.

Comment: In such situation I use SQLite, it is easy to setup and use.   https://nickcharlton.net/posts/sqlite-with-csharp.html

Comment: @doro Interesting, thanks for the suggestion. Does the destination computer need SQLite in order to install the program?

Comment: Nope, that is the point.  You need to install sqlite ONLY on the developer computer.  At the begining I was not happy in using sqlite (it was a project requirement) but later I discover that it is a great solution, as long it is used as small local database.   However, if you need to insert huge amount of data, you should use transaction, otherwise the insertion will be quite slow.

Comment: If I can do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8495991/2374028 I would prefer to do that then edit the code directly using SQLite. If that's not possible I'll take your advice and probably follow this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/153407/WPF-and-SQLite-Database

Comment: I don't really understand your question, it is quite easy to implement.  I usually access sqlite using ado.net.  Can you sent me some of your code example?

Comment: Sure, I updated the question to explain how I'm using the database now.

Comment: Thank you for the update.  Well, you cannot use Linq with SQLIte, unless you use some external library.  However, I am not sure if you can use SQL Server compact on a machine without SQL Server installed.  I mean, the destinaton computer should have installed SQL Server in order to run your application.  I personal suggest to use SQLIte, so you not need to worry whether the computer which run the application have or not have SQL Server installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here's how I did it.

1. create excel spreadsheet of data
2. open microsoft sql server management studio express 2014
3. create new database
4. tasks -> import data 
   a) source microsoft excel, pick file
   b) destination Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server
5. rename table whatever you want
6. run query to add uniqueidentifier to each row

   `ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ADD NewColumn UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT newsequentialid() NOT null`
7. detach database
8. open Visual Studios 2013
9. right click project, add new item, .dbml file (LINQ-SQL something)
10. from server explorer, drag in your table to the dbml designer
11. choose yes, you do want to copy your database into the file, this should 
    load and .mdf into your program
12. in the designer.cs file, go to the columnattribute for your uniqueidentifier column, and add the attribute `IsPrimaryKey=true` after the `DbType`.
13. set the .mdf properties to "Content" and "Copy always"